# direct SQL Query working and and sql query via php not?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to execute the following query via php's  mysql_query function but it's not working.

When I execute it directly (via phpMyAdmin's sql tab) it does work. Any idea what's going on?

```
Update t1 SET r ='[{"Ia":36.009,"Ja":-78.93},{"Ia":36.01,"Ja":-78.93}]' WHERE id=1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to escape double quotes with \ ?

Comment: @Nick Tried it with them escaped and stil no luck

Comment: @Nick Turns out you were right, but unfortunately when I tried it escaped the first time I forgot to quote the value of ID as well, which is what was actually causing the error, @BDesign's response got me to go back and try it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you use it. You have to escape your quotes. So it should be :

```
mysql_query('Update t1 SET r =\'[{"Ia":36.009,"Ja":-78.93},{"Ia":36.01,"Ja":-78.93}]\' WHERE id=1');
```

OR

```
mysql_query("Update t1 SET r ='[{\"Ia\":36.009,\"Ja\":-78.93},{\"Ia\":36.01,\"Ja\":-78.93}]' WHERE id=1");
```

Anyway, that is not pretty safe. You should have a look over prepared statements, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) .

Standard mysql is old and lacks of lots of features.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, it was the latter that I needed to do. Also thanks for the advice on PDO and MySQLi, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

When you do it like this

```
mysql_query('Update t1 SET r ='[{"Ia":36.009,"Ja":-78.93},{"Ia":36.01,"Ja":-78.93}]' WHERE id=1');
```

it wont work. You need to escape it like this:

```
mysql_query('Update t1 SET r =\'[{"Ia":36.009,"Ja":-78.93},{"Ia":36.01,"Ja":-78.93}]\' WHERE id=1');
```

Comment: Hey Martin, tried what you said and it still didn't work. Pretty sure doing that caused the value of r to not be sent as one congruent string, which sounds like it shouldn't work?